# Dual Monitor (IGP with GPU) in Linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, gpu

I've been googling although I couldn't find an answer to this question:

How in the world can I enable both my IGP and GPU in order to have a dual monitor setup?

I've got an **Intel** IGP (00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)) and an **ATI** Radeon GPU with its propietary drivers. I've seen in the BIOS of my **ASRock** that there is some IGD Dual Display setting or something like that, but I tried enabling it and it didn't work. I tried booting using the IGP as preferred display and Fedora couldn't end booting because it said there was "no display" to use (actually, the boot process didn't continue after "[ OK ] Reached target graphical interface" so I entered terminal mode and executed startx which said that there was no monitor to use). I am using an Intel Core i5-2310 CPU so I assume I do have this new Intel technology of being able to use the IGP and the GPU. What's going on?